# Appengine endpoint client library creation in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, client-library

I have a java based appengine endpoint project in eclipse.

When I generate client library using command line tool.

> https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/endpoints_tool

I'm getting only source based jar file ('project_name_version'.java-1.18.0-rc-sources.jar). It does not work fine in Android Studio when I add as a Library.

How can I get class based jar client library (google-api-services-'project_name_verison'-1.18.0-rc.jar)?

I tried searching online but no luck yet.

Comment: Did you found a solution for this? I am having the same issue with my endpoint / java project. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could always zip up the sources file and use them in Android Studio. However , note that in the build.gradle file, you will have to reference the other dependent JAR files + versions that will be needed by the sources that you have generated in Eclipse via the Generate Cloud Endpoint Library option.

Answer (score 0):

Build your app engine back end with JRE 7. You can change this from windows->preferences->java->installed JREs. You'll find an Add button at the right side of the pane. For more detail refer this [Tutorial](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-add_new_jre.htm)

This will solve most of your problems.